# WebService doesn't read web.config

Tags: c#, web-services, web-config

I've got 3 connectionstrings in web.config, and  I used theirs like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeName"].ConnectionString))
```

Every metgod is called by winforms application.

One of webmethods doesn't work properly because it reads only one connectionString:

```
data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

It's not a connectionString from my web.config .

I invoke every method in the same way.

How it's impossible ??

EDITED:

I use facade: This is structure: 
WinForms calls WebMethod SaveItem
SaveItem calls method on Facade: SaveItemAndDoDatabaseStuff 
SaveItemAndDoDatabaseStuff does database stuff.

Comment: Can you provide some clarification?
-second line you mention that you are using connection strings in your web.config
-third line you mention that you are using winforms (winforms use app.config and not web.config)
-facade: is this the design pattern or some piece of software?

Comment: Database part is on webservice. WinForms application is client

Comment: Does all the three connection string point to SQL Server?

Comment: @phenevo check my answer, there is a high chance that'll work for your scenario.

Comment: @Raja yes...but problem disappear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't see your web structure, but is it possible that your app isn't configured as an application in IIS, therefore is picking up the *master* web.config? Which would look *exactly* like that...

Go into IIS and ensure it is an application (it may have a cog icon).

Answer (score 1):

If your WinForms application talks directly to database X (*not* via the web service), then the connection string for database X should be in app.config (in the WinForms project).

If your Web Service (as I understand, this includes your facade and your database layer), talks to databases X, Y and Z, then the connection strings for X, Y, and Z need to be in web.config (in the Web Services Project).

Answer (score 1):

It's using the default connection string asp.net has (in the machine.config in the .net installation folders).

Do a clear:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    ... your connection strings here
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Btw, when you say you are using "SomeName" in the connection string. It isn't surely any random connection string you used, its the default: "LocalSqlServer".

Answer (score 0):

You should store the connection-strings in the `web.config` or `app.config` in whatever project that you are executing.

In your case, you should have the connection-strings in your app.config for your winforms application.

Comment: No, I use facade: This is structure:

WinForms calls WebMethod SaveItem

SaveItem calls method on Facade: SaveItemAndDoDatabaseStuff

SaveItemAndDoDatabaseStuff does database stuff.

Only this method doesn't work.

Comment: -1 OP had already mentioned that the DB was used from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a Trace line to print out the configuration file being used just before you ask for the connection string.  Simply add the following line:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(
            System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile,
            "APP_CONFIG");
```

Set a breakpoint after this and look at the Output window for a line that starts with "APP_CONFIG:".  This will give the full path to the configuration file and allow you to determine where it's being loaded.  If you still see a discrepancy between the runtime values and the configuration file then likely something is changing those values at runtime within your application.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but perhaps worthwhile.

I have a web-service project, and I want to run it in two modes.

One is "local as app" (for testing), and for that, at least in my current system setup, the file where it reads from is
Web.config (which it apparently reads in deug mode INSTEAD of Web.Debug.config, at least for database configuration)

So, one replace the  attribute section with  and copy in the ones you  would use in the "Calling project for hte web service).

So replace

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDB" 
    connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

with

```
<appSettings>
        <!-- Database Connection -->
        <add key="AppDatabase" value="RedactedDatabase"/>
        <add key="AppLoginID" value="RedactedLoginID"/>
        <add key="AppLoginPwd" value="RedactedPwd"/>
</appSettings>
```

The above  are found in app.config in the "calling project".... To me, this is more elegant anyway.

Now it will work in both modes.

One could use a conditional compile in the C#, but now you just read it in:

C# code:

```
String whichDatabase = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppDatabase"]; 

   String appUsedID = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppLoginID"]; 
   String appUsedPwd = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppLoginPwd"];
```

The above works in either mode, without conditional compile directives.